# R - How to use catagorical data on Histogram

Tags: r

I have exhausted every different approach I could find and the issue always went back to numeric values, none of the table and factor got me close but I always fell short.

This is as close as I got with a Bar Chart

```
library(dplyr)
my_data <- read.csv("vehicle.csv")

mutate(trans = factor(trans, labels = c("auto", "man")),
       model = factor(model))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = model, fill = trans)) +
  geom_bar()
```

But I specifically need to make it a full histogram, I have tried every method I could find starting with ggplot2 and moving onto every library with an example offered. Both trans and model are categorial data, it would be nice to figure it out to the point where I could exchange one of those for numeric as well.

Thanks

Comment: it's hard to help you when we have no idea what your data looks like. can you follow the steps in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to see in your histogram?  Histograms are specifically meant for graphing numerical data, while bar charts will work for categorical data.  It may help if you also include some of your data.

Comment: Hey @Toronto51 did the solution below ended up being useful? If yes, please don't forget to mark it as accepted answer to help other navigate more easily to the working solutions in the future. If not, I would be very happy to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a simple histogram of either you `trans` or `model` variables you first need to compute their frequencies. For this you would need to count how many time each model appears and how many times it is manual or automatic.

If your data is something like:

```
my_data <- data.frame(model=as.factor(c("audi", "vw", "audi", "audi")), trans=as.factor(c("manual", "auto", "manual", "auto")))
```

Then,

```
my_data %>%
  table %>% 
  barplot()
```

or a better solution using `ggplot()`:

```
my_data %>% 
  table %>% 
  data.frame %>%
  ggplot(., aes(y=Freq, x=model, fill=trans))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

But again, this is based on an assumption of how your data looks like. Here's how it looks:

[image]